# How can you replace an integer value in a .rdl report in visual studio with some type of assigned text?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, reporting-services

I am pulling data for a report from a stored procedure. One of the fields on the stored procedure is an integer field (coming from a drop down list value 1,2,3 ect). How can I make it so that I can assign these integer values to the actual text from the drop down list? Do I have to create a function in the stored procedure somehow?

For example, right now when I assign the field on the report it just reads the integer value from the drop down list, such as 1. This is how the data is stored in the database. I want it to read the drop down text (such as  Bicycle that is in the actual drop down) instead of the actual number. There are a total of 4 values.

Comment: Can you store these drop down values in a database table?  If so, you can just return those as part of your stored procedure.

Comment: I store them as integer values from the drop down (1,2,3, ect) are in the table. The table is linked to a lookup table that describes what the product actually is based on the integer value.

Comment: My question was if you can store the lookup table itself in the database.  It is generally advisable to avoid hardcoded lookups, unless they are immutable concepts (True vs False, Up vs Down, etc)

Comment: @user1049984: It isn't clear whether you want to display the text description of the **parameter** in the report (for example in the report header), or the text description of the corresponding procedure output **field**. It also isn't clear whether the description is stored in a database (whether it is the same database or a different database), and whether or not you are able to amend the stored procedure to include the description as one of the returned fields. The answer to this question could depend on all of these factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can create a function on your stored procedure. This function would receive an integer as a parameter and return a string containing the description. It'd be good these descriptions be stored on a lookup table. However, using functions would slow things a bit.

Another and better way would be just use a INNER JOIN on you stored procedure query.

Something like:

select MT.ID, MT.NAME, MT.LOOKUP_ID, LT.ID, LT.NAME 
from MAIN_TABLE MT inner join LOOKUP_TABLE LT on MT.LOOKUP_ID = LT.ID